# What is the reason of high CPU usage on a 64 bit OS?

Tags: python, multithreading, mechanize

I found it very interesting and yet don't know why: One of my python scripts runs **effortlessly on a 32 bit win 2003 machine**(20% CPU usage or even less), while the exact same script almost **cost 100% CPU on a 64 bit win 2008 machine**. The two machines have **the same level of hardware.**

Basically the script is multi-threaded using `threading` and `mechanize` module to scrape specific results from dozens of web pages.

Anyway, what is the reason of high CPU usage on that 64 bit OS?

**Edit:**

I'm actually trying to find some general cautions when migrating multi-threaded scripts from 32 bit to 64 bit.

OK, here's what's the codes like:

```
def SpawnThreads(amounts, urls_queue, proxies_queue):

    for counter in range(amounts):
        new_thread = threading.Thread(target = CheckResults, args = (urls_queue, proxies_queue， ))
        new_thread.start()

def CheckResults(urls_queue, proxies_queue):
    if urls_queue.empty():
         return 1

    if proxies_queue.empty():
        return 1

    get url from urls_queue

    get proxy from proxies_queue

    get html source of url

    put proxy back to proxies_queue if everything's all right

    spawn_a_new_thread = threading.Thread(target = SpawnThreads, args = (1, urls_queue, proxies_queue)
    spawn_a_new_thread.start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    put all urls into urls_queue
    put all proxies into proxies_queue

    SpawnThreads(100, urls_queue, proxies_queue)
```

Comment: Same number of cores and threads per core on the two machines?

Comment: Threading always hurts the processor.

Comment: Threading does not *"hurt the processor"*, it just saturates it. What is the point of having a processor **not** at 100% utilization for tasks like this anyway?

Comment: Which versions of OS are each of the machines?

Comment: I don't really get why this question was closed. Can somebody explain ?

Comment: Sorry Shane. Here you can ask narrow technical questions. We don't have enough people here to see such a big picture your question needs to be answered.

Comment: @dystroy there are scant details to base an answer on; any answer proposed would be speculation given the way the question is now, violates; not constructive and too localized at best probably others. If it is edited and updated heavily I will vote to reopen.

Comment: @dystroy: it's pretty light on details that would let us help the OP, but I think it's still answerable, albeit with a little psychic debugging. Voting to reopen.

Comment: Shane, post as much of your code that you think is relevant.

Comment: Need OS specifications more than anything.

Comment: Guys, just added some codes above. Actually I was trying to find some general cautions when migrating multi-threaded scripts from 32 bit to 64 bit.

Answer (score 1):

One thing that really jumps out is all those threads spawning other threads in a circular manner (`SpawnThreads`->`CheckResults`->`SpawnThreads`->`...`).

Even though each thread is supposed to die soon after it's called `other_thread.start()`, constantly spawning threads could well turn out to be the bottleneck.

If I were you, the first thing I'd do is sort out the threading logic. Something like a pool of worker threads might be a good fit for the problem.